# Where can I create an online playlist (without necessarily the feature to play them)?

Tags: playlists

I would like to create a playlist online. Like collecting proposals/ideas of songs & artists.

I don't need to play them right there. The creation of the list is the feature I'm looking for.

Are there sites like this out there? Ideally this is possible to work on the list collaboratively.

Another feature that I am looking for is searching for titles / autocompletion. Thus Google docs are out of the equation.

Comment: If you don't actually need to play them, won't any online document system work for you? e.g. google docs or outlook.com ?

Comment: Ahh, I'll add this. I want to be able to search/autocomplete also.  http://mixtape.me/ offers something like it, but not for collaboration.

Comment: What happens if all the people collaborating just log in to mixtape.me with the same username / password?

Comment: That might be an idea, and I keep it in reserve if what I'm looking for does not exist in its pure form.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is asking for an off-site resource.

Comment: I agree that this question isn't really a good fit for this SE as your more looking for a product. I'm not 100% sure, but it may be within the scope of the Software Recs SE.

Comment: I couldn't find any real restrictions what to ask and what not to ask for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used in the end [Rdio](http://www.rdio.com/) because collaboration worked. Even though it was a little difficult, it was possible to copy the songs from the list, in copying directly the text from the homepage. 
This is definitely not a best fit for what I was looking for, but it worked. 
Also: I'm not sure rdio's terms of use allow this, but anyway it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I do recommend [Rate Your Music](https://rateyourmusic.com/), because on RYM you are not only able to create [lists](https://rateyourmusic.com/lists/) consisting of albums or songs, you can also include anything related (artists, even different releases of the same title).

The other features (ratings, reviews, [charts](https://rateyourmusic.com/customchart)) are also worth a shot.

Comment: Looks like this site could really provide the feature, but I didn't find any way to add a song to a list. Only Artists or Labels or full Albums.

Comment: Looks like I can add only singles or albums, not each song separately. So it doesn't fit exactly what I am looking for.